# How to incercept IP based HTTPS connections using burp proxy?

Tags: ssl, https, proxy, sniffing

I have setup burp proxy on the default gateway in a transparent mode. Burp suite is displaying self signed certificate to web based HTTPS clients and intercepting the traffic. However, it is not able to intercept the IP based traffic.

E.g. It can intercept https://abc.xyz.com but not https://192.168.132.129

Is there any way to intercept such traffic? I am open to solution other than Burp as well.

Answer (score 0):

In that case I'll suggest the [OWASP Zed Attack Proxy](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project) :)

Its free, open source, and easy to use (I'm biased;)

You can create your own root CA cert which you can then import into your browser so that HTTPS traffic can be handled correctly.

You can also tell ZAP which IP addresses it should ignore.

Let me know if you have any questions about it.

Simon (ZAP Project Lead)